# Ошибка при логировании

Tags: android

Добрый день, есть файл (TEST.txt), в который должно вестись логирование.

Собственно, вот логирование:

```
    public void loger() throws IOException {

    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
         fw = new FileWriter(new File("sdcard/TEST.txt"), true);

        fw.write("все ок");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            fw.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Логирование должно вестись в файл на телефоне, под управлением Android. Но из-за прав доступа кидает ошибки.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` в данной ситуации не работает, т.к. нет исходников проекта.

Comment: Что этот кусок кода вообще логирует? И где он у вас находится, если у вас нет доступа к манифесту?

Comment: можно проект перепаковать, исправив манифест.

Comment: А чем вас Log не устраивает?

Comment: @rasmisha, я тестирую проект, но у меня нет его исходников - есть только *.apk. Соответственно от манифеста толка почти нет. 
Логирую я банальное - что-то закончилось делать и в лог записалось мол все ок.

@KoVadim, пробовал - не работает

@RomanoO, лог немного не то, FileWriter бы мне :) но из-за прав не могу его юзать :(

Comment: Не понимаю все равно, либо добавляют ваш кусок без вас и вы можете сказать, чтобы добавили нужные permissions, либо у вас свое приложение, тогда и манифест свой

Comment: @rasmisha, имеется тестовый проект на основе apk-шки, пишутся тесты при помощи определенный либы (к исходникам я не имеют доступа + манифесте указываются только пакеты и не более того) вот мне и хочется, чтобы после определенного теста данные заносились в лог

Comment: какие такие "определенные либы"?
А может просто в лог писать и будет все ок? А не изобретать свой мегалог.

Comment: @KoVadim, Robotium. 
Log.D(); вариант, но это не то, чего я хочу и главное чего от меня хотят :)

Ну и я бы не назвал Filewriter мега логом :)

Comment: Тяжелая работа у взломщиков :)